# Pass GoogleMap as Parameter to fragment

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a problem with my Android application using Google Maps API V2.

I have a FragmentActivity with two fragments. One fragment with a list and one fragment with a GoogleMap-object. what i want to achieve is to manipulate the map from the list.

In my FragmentActivity I initiate my map-fragment like this:

```
customMapFragment = MapSectionFragment.newInstance();
```

In my FragmentActivity I initiate my GoogleMap like this:

```
mMap = customMapFragment.getMap();
```

This reference - the mMap - is what I want to pass in to my list-fragment, like this:

```
listSectionFragment = new ListSectionFragment(mMap);
```

This I want to do so I easily can manipulate the specific map on the map-fragment from the list-fragment class. This is my constructor:

```
    public ListSectionFragment(GoogleMap mMap) {
    this.mMap = mMap;
}
```

However, this gives me the error/warning *"Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle) instead"*

And since a GoogleMap is not parcelable I cannot send it via a bundle.

How to solve this issue without a default constructor?

---

EDIT:
I am suppressing the warning and it seems to work fine. But as the explanation for the warning tells me: *Every fragment must have an empty constructor, so it can be instansiated when restoring its activity's state.*

Will this kick back at me at some point with random crashes? The best option is still to solve the issue without a default constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

use onAttached instead of default constructor.

like this:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if(!(activity instanceof MainFragmentActivity))
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must be of type MainFragmentActivity");
    parent = (MainFragmentActivity) activity;
    this.mMap = parent.getMap();
}
```